# Can't register voice trigger on glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

My glass app isn't able to find the "name" to use for the voice trigger. The command is showing up in the "ok glass... " list, but i get this exception when the app installs:

```
12-27 18:11:31.372      460-460/? W/VoiceTrigger﹕ Unable to get info for trigger: ComponentInfo{com.my_foo2/com.my_foo2.Glass.UiService}
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.my_foo2/com.my_foo2.Glass.UiService}
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getServiceInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:253)
        at com.google.android.glass.app.VoiceTrigger.getInfo(VoiceTrigger.java:290)
        at com.google.android.glass.app.VoiceTrigger.loadLabel(VoiceTrigger.java:263)
        at com.google.glass.home.voice.menu.MainMenuGrammarLoader.getDisambiguationGraph(MainMenuGrammarLoader.java:124)
        at com.google.glass.home.voice.menu.MainMenuGrammarLoader.reloadDisambiguationConfigs(MainMenuGrammarLoader.java:77)
        at com.google.glass.home.voice.menu.MainMenuGrammarLoader.reloadGrammars(MainMenuGrammarLoader.java:73)
        at com.google.glass.home.voice.menu.MainMenuGrammarLoader.registerForUpdates(MainMenuGrammarLoader.java:137)
        at com.google.glass.input.VoiceInputHelper.registerGrammarLoaders(VoiceInputHelper.java:576)
        at com.google.glass.input.VoiceInputHelper.dispatchVoiceServiceConnected(VoiceInputHelper.java:571)
        at com.google.glass.input.VoiceInputHelper.access$400(VoiceInputHelper.java:41)
        at com.google.glass.input.VoiceInputHelper$2.handleMessage(VoiceInputHelper.java:171)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the service declaration xml:

```
<service
        android:name=".Glass.UiService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/main_icon"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
            android:resource="@xml/sb_show" />
    </service>
```

i seem to be doing the same exact things as the code samples, but keep getting this exception. thoughts?

*EDIT*

sb_show.xml is

```
<trigger keyword="@string/show_voice_trigger"/>
```

and show voice trigger is my trigger string ("show blah")

Comment: Could you also include the contents of xml/sb_show.xml?

Comment: I agree with @tony-allevato - try the full package name for your app in service@android:name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue seems to have been with the "disambiguation" part of the stack trace, and the exception itself doesn't seem to have mattered.

The string was "record a ," and it seems to have confused the speech recognizer. "Record a video" continued to work, but the second I changed "record a " to "get a ," it started working fine.

Comment: Was the full trigger string "record a ," exactly as you typed it there, or are you leaving part of it out? Either way, this sounds like something that might still be worth filing as a bug in our issue tracker so we can investigate it, with as many details as possible: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list

Comment: i'm leaving the noun after "a" out, but the rest is right. i'll file the bug.

Answer (score 0):

`com.my_foo2.Glass.UiService` is the correct fully-qualified name for your service class, correct? And I'm assuming that the `package` attribute of your `manifest` tag is `com.my_foo2`?

If so, can you try using the fully-qualified class name in the `android:name` attribute of your `service` tag instead of the dot-prefixed shorthand version and see if that has any effect?